# Остановить лишние процессы в контроллере

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Добрый день. Пытаюсь оптимизировать работу Autocomplete строки поиска на сайте. Проблема в том, что при вводе текста поиска в контроллер, поступают запросы побуквенно. Например, при поиске слова "привет", приходят параллельно запросы "п", "пр", "при", "прив", "приве", "привет". Необходимо при получении следующего запроса в рамках сеанса, останавливать работу контроллера предыдущих запросов. Для этого думаю нужна глобальная переменная, которая принимала бы значения во время этих запросов. Пробовал Session и TempData - не вышло, т.к. похоже их значения 
в глобальную переменную передаются после окончания работы контроллера или получения ответа от браузера. Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Comment: отменяйте запросы на клиентской стороне. если пользователь печатает быстро - это достаточно эффективно прервет запрос до того, как он дойдет до сервера.

Comment: и не оптимизируйте это на сервере. такие запросы должны быть легкими, вы больше серверных ресурсов потратите на синхронизацию, прерывание и поддержку сессии, чем на просто обработку всех запросов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы переусложняете. В случае с автодополнением достаточно просто настроить его чувствительность. Например, отправлять запрос на сервер только если в поле ввода не менее 3 символов. 
Скажем, в случае использования JqueryUI это можно сделать примерно так:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  minLength: 3
});
```

Использовать какие-либо глобальные переменные и следить за предыдущими запросами совершенно неправильно. Во-первых, сами по себе глобальные переменные - плохая идея, а во-вторых, представьте ситуацию: два разных пользователя примерно в одно и то же время вводят какие-то строки в ваш автокомплит. Скажем, первый ввёл "кот", его запрос ушел на сервер. Затем второй хочет ввести "коттедж", и его запрос тоже ушел на сервер. По вашей логике получается, что необходимо отменить выполнение первого запроса, и, соответственно, первый пользователь либо получит ответ, что про кота ничего не найдено, либо же ему придется ждать выполнения запроса второго пользователя, и получить информацию не про кота, а про коттедж. Это корректное поведение? Сомневаюсь.

UPD

Если запрос к бд очень медленный, то, во-первых, попробуйте соптимизировать его или добавить нужные индексы, а во-вторых, добавьте кэширование результатов этого запроса чтобы не обращаться каждый раз к бд, а брать уже готовые данные из кэша. Как правило, данные, возвращаемые автокомплитом - это довольно-таки статичные данные (например, города-страны), и меняются нечасто, поэтому время жизни кэша может быть достаточно долгим. 
Идея с задержкой, предложенная @tym32167, кстати, тоже вполне годная. Пусть лишние нажатия отсеиваются на клиенте, а не на сервере

Comment: Я бы ещё добавил задержку в 0.5-1 секунды перед тем, как отправлять запрос. Чтобы запрос уходил только если юзер перестал печатать.

Comment: minLength у меня выставлен. Идея в том что переменная должна быть в пределах сессии, а не глобальная сайта. Просто выборка из БД у меня тяжелая и minLength помогает частично. ну а задержка в 0,5-1 сек - это всё же задержка.

Comment: @Frol4ic обновил ответ

Comment: @Frol4ic Вообще такая задержка - обычная практика - чтобы не перегружать сервер. Зачем юзеру отправлять запросы на сервер, если он ещё не закончил ввод?

Comment: @Frol4ic По сути, у вас же и проблема в том, что вы отправляете ненужные запросы, а потом хотите их отменить. Я просто предложил их не отправлять :)

Comment: @tym32167 отправка запросов сразу же, без секундной задержки - это стандартная практика в любой допечатке. Например, гугловский поиск себя так ведет. В системе, где допечатка важна, секундная задержка воспринимается очень неприятно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. На этом и остановлюсь)

Comment: @PashaPash Это справедливо для запросов, которые выполняются мгновенно. Но тут автор же вроде написал, что запрос тяжелый. Имеет ли смысл досить БД тяжелыми запросами и потом отменять их? Ну и не понятно, для чего используются эти запросы у автора - для допечаток или поиска результатов по указанному тексту

Comment: @tym32167 имеет смысл взять и вынести допечатку в какой-нибудь apache lucene / suggesters, а не искать лайком по базе.

Comment: У меня запрос по поиску результатов с использованием полнотекстового поиска MSSQL без всяких лайков. Просто сразу из многих таблиц.

Comment: @Frol4ic full text не будет работать достаточно быстро для Autocomplete. Для быстрого поиска без задержек стоит синхронизировать данные в apache lucene / solr (можно попробовать в виде azure search service), и использовать допечатку оттуда - там есть быстрый механизм поиска именно для autocomplete.

Comment: @Frol4ic В общем, у вас варианты: Пробовать отменять запросы ещё на клиенте и смириться / не отправлять ненужные запросы на сервер и все равно смириться / использовать специально предназначенные для поиска по индексированному тексту инструменты типа lucene/solr и радоваться / Писать свой велосипед на бекенде и подпирать его потом костылями. ИМХО, велосипеды  писать - себе дороже.